# remsh on ssh enabled machines

Tags: unix, ssh

Recently all our testing machines have been moved to a secured shell network. As a result, ip addresses of all these machines has now been changed and we have to access these machines using SSH protocol now onwards.

However, I am not able to access any target machine which is also enabled for SSH using "remsh" to perform some task.

I have checked the existence of ".rhosts" file and and entry of the target machine's ip entry into "/etc/hosts" file.

Kindly let me know if I need to change/look any where else to make remsh work?

Answer (score 0):

Remsh, rlogin, rsh, and rcp are not a secure systems as information is sent as plain text between the machines and because the hosts verification is not done with secret keys but is host-based and can be forged. I would think that you have changed to ssh precisely for these reasons.

Luckily you can do all the same things using ssh. For example, after configuring the machines to use public & private key pairs, you can run commmands on remote machine automatically (by supplying password or using passwordless keys):

`ssh user@remotehost command-to-be-run`

If you haven't used ssh much earlier, there are a lot of things to learn, but isn't that fun? As a result you will also know how to do state of the art secure connections. You will want to learn especially about public key authentication.

There are lots of tutorials on the Internet how to create and use keys and use ssh. http://www.olearycomputers.com/ll/ssh_guide.html seems like a good starting point. https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/SSHReplacingRhosts discusses specifically replacing .rhosts authentication with a key pair.